# How to disable back button after splash screen in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

after I finished loading the splash screen and going to the main page, I pressed it back again to go back to the splash screen ..

and the question is how to overcome this, so that after entering the main page I can't go back to the splash screen either from the button or back button on the phone keyboard,

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: How are you navigating from Splash screen to Main page ? Are you using React Navigation ? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: i just use this code >> 

componentWillMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
    }, 3000)
  }

======================================
after splash screen is gone and im in Home , i try to press back button and it back again to splash screen and stuck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use BackHandler for this.
Documentation
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler

```
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {

    return true;  // Do nothing when back button is pressed
  }
```

Comment: it's work on every screen, How to Avoid that?
or can you check here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306718/how-to-handle-exit-app-in-one-screen-not-in-the-whole-app-react-native

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using expo this is the best place to look how splash screen works.
[splash-screens](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/splash-screens)
[app-loading](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading.html)

Comment: please review how to answer a question on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using a stack navigator. Change it to a switch navigator and you'll not navigate to the previous screen when pressing *back*.

Here is a basic working example :

https://snack.expo.io/@sanjar/so-53764740

ps : In this example, I'm using react-navigation 2 (the latest version is 3).

Comment: but where should i use that? in app.js or splash.js ?

Comment: i just use this code >> componentWillMount(){ setTimeout(()=>{ this.props.navigation.navigate('Home'); }, 3000) } 

==========================================
i using this code for redirect to Home