# How to handle exit app in one screen not in the whole app - React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have some issue with **BackHandler**, the issue is

when running the app and go to the let's say Sign Up screen and touch the back in my mobile they will run the function and show the Alert to confirm, but now when I go to any other screen and touch the back they will I need to just back to the previous screen on every back BackHandler.exitApp(); runs, Although I write if the routname is SignUp just exit the app not other screens

this is my code

#### Sign Up

```
    import React from "react";
    import {
      Text,
      TextInput,
      ActivityIndicator,
      View,
      KeyboardAvoidingView,
      ScrollView,
      Image,
      TouchableOpacity,
      BackHandler,
      Alert
    } from "react-native";
    export default class signUp extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

      }

      componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.backPressed);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.backPressed);
      }
      backPressed = () => {
    let { routeName } = this.props.navigation.state;
    console.log("route is :  " + routeName);

    if (routeName == "SignUp") {
      console.log("ROUTE :  " + routeName);
      Alert.alert(
        "Exit App",
        "Do you want to exit?",
        [
          {
            text: "No",
            onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
            style: "cancel"
          },
          { text: "Yes", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

      render() {....}
    }
```

#### Routes

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import Splash from "../screens/Splash";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import SignUp from "../screens/SignUp";
import SignIn from "../screens/SignIn";
import ForgetPassword from "../screens/ForgetPassword";

const Routes = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Splash: {
      screen: Splash,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    SignUp: {
      screen: SignUp,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        // header: null
        title: "Sign Up",
        headerLeft: null,
        headerTintColor: "#fc0301",
        headerStyle: {
          borderBottomColor: "white"
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
          color: "#fc0301",
          textAlign: "center",
          flex: 1,
          elevation: 0,
          fontSize: 25,
          justifyContent: "center"
        }
      })
    },
    SignIn: {
      screen: SignIn,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Sign In",
        headerRight: <View />,
        headerTintColor: "#fc0301",
        headerStyle: {
          borderBottomColor: "white"
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
          color: "#fc0301",
          textAlign: "center",
          flex: 1,
          elevation: 0,
          fontSize: 25,
          justifyContent: "center"
        }
      }
    },
    ForgetPassword: {
      screen: ForgetPassword,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Splash"
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(Routes);
```

Comment: The default BackButton functionality is to:

Move one step toward the top of your stack, and if you're already on the top, it will exit the app,

`return true;` to prevent the default behavior, pressing your back button will do nothing.

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli hmm, the simple issue is when I'm in the SignUp screen and click on the **hardware back button** it will move me to the Splash screen and it's abnormal!
so the idea is I need to just in Sign up screen and some i want screen I want to disable hardware back button,
not in every screen

i talk here about "BackHandler Android "

Comment: Your issue here could be solved by using a `SwitchNavigator` that would render: 1. Splash screen. 2. Your StackNavigator

once you're directed to your stack, the backButton will never take you back to your Splash screen

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli Sorry about this comment, but I am stuck, have you any example to implement One to One chat"private" NOT **Room** using firebase as backend !?

Answer (score 9):

You can check for the screen has been focused prior to call the alert instead of checking the `routeName` from navigation.

the updated code might look like this.

```
if (this.props.navigation.isFocused()) {
    Alert.alert(
    "Exit App",
    "Do you want to exit?",
    [
      {
        text: "No",
        onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
        style: "cancel"
      },
      { text: "Yes", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
    );
}
```

Comment: yes, that's work, If I need to run the alert in the many screens I need to call this function in every screen?
for example, I wanna run the alert in *SignUp* and "Home" and some other!

Comment: If you have specific screens that needs this functionality, you can use it in a common service class and call it on componentDidMount. so that it will be easy to maintain.

Comment: How can i handle it in react-navigation V5

Comment: seems like it is no longer the case in v5, `navigation.isFocused()` always returns true and worse is `navigation.canGoBack()` always returns false, I have no idea how to know when I am on top most of the stack and really can't go back anymore

Comment: have you tried using a counter redux action, we have used global counter before finding this solution.
it will always work!

Comment: @Zennichimaro I'm on version 5 and from my tests, `navigation.canGoBack()` is working well. It shows `false` when you're at the root of the stack and shows `true` when I'm nested down at least 1 screen in the stack. Not sure how your finding this or maybe they've updated it since you tried it. I'm on `"@react-navigation/native": "5.9.8", "@react-navigation/stack": "5.14.9"`

Answer (score 3):

#### Version 5+, try using `navigation.canGoBack()`.

I discovered this from [Zennichimaro's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306718/how-to-handle-exit-app-in-one-screen-not-in-the-whole-app-react-native#comment115128607_55333049).

##### If there's only one screen in your stack.

```js
navigation.canGoBack() //=> false
```

##### If there's at least one screen below you in the stack.

*i.e. If there's a screen that you can go "back" to.*

```js
navigation.canGoBack() //=> false

navigation.navigate( "screen2" );

navigation.canGoBack() //=> true

navigation.goBack();

navigation.canGoBack() //=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {Alert, BackHandler} from 'react-native';


useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const handleBackPress = () => {
        Alert.alert(
          'Exit App',
          'Do you want to exit?',
          [
            {
              text: 'No',
              onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
              style: 'cancel',
            },
            {
              text: 'Yes',
              onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp(),
            },
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
        return true; // Prevents the default back action
      };
      const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackPress);
      return () => {
        backHandler.remove();
      };
    }, [])
  );
```

Comment: As is, this answer does not meet community guidelines. What exactly did you do do to solve the question and why? Posting code without explanation is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the `navigation` object of your **ROOT** navigator by calling `dangerouslyGetParent` recursively

**For Example**
If your have that heirarchy:

- BottomTabs (TabNavigator)

  - Browser (StackNavigator)
  - Settings (StackNavigator)

    - About (Screen)

And you want to get the current `routeName` in your `androidBackHandler`
which is wired in your `Browser` screen, then you should get the navigation object of your `BottomTabs` by calling `dangerouslyGetParent` **twice** (which is the depth of your navigation tree):

```
const bottomTabsNavigation = navigation
      .dangerouslyGetParent()
      .dangerouslyGetParent();
```

If you tried to `console.log` your `bottomTabsNavigation` when you're on `About` screen, you should see something like that

[image]

Comment: sadly didn't work :/ in every screen I show the Alert

Comment: I write your code just add case "SignIn" alert"something" to test them in the Sign In screen

Comment: I made some magic I don't know why it's work :D
i just replace **routeName** with 
`this.props.navigation.isFocused()`
and it's work finally !!

Answer (score 0):

If the screen where you wish to handle the back button press is the one before the app should close, you can add this to the screen.

```
 import {createNavigationContainerRef} from '@react-navigation/native';

 const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();
 const goBack = () => navigationRef?.canGoBack();

 const App = () => {
   // ...
   useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        StatusBar.setHidden(false);
      }, 500);

      const backAction = () => {
        if (goBack) {
          return false;
        } else {
          setAlertVisible(true);
          return true;
        }
      };

      const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        backAction,
      );

      return () => backHandler.remove();
    }, []);
   // ...
 }
```

If not, you can replace the contents of `goBack` to a condition that provides your desired effects.